# How can I do a CSS selector similar to .hasClass() jQuery method in CSS?

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following html tag:

```
<li class="menu expanded">
```

I need to bind a click event to `li` tag when it has a class menu.

I'm trying with this selector: `li[class="menu"]`, but when it has the class `expanded` too it doesn't not work.

Comment: why not just do `$('li.menu')` ?

Comment: I tried but does not work

Comment: make sure you wrap it inside a document.ready function()  - it should work fine

Comment: ..and you are including jQuery in your page.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking to select the list item that has both the menu AND expanded classes, use:

```
$('li.menu.expanded').click(function(){
//stuff
})
```

otherwise

```
$('li.menu').click(function(){
//stuff
})
```

would suffice.

Answer (score 3):

This selector should work

```
$('li.menu')
```

Will select all `li` tags containing `menu` class, no matter if it's the only css class or not.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the raw jQuery attribute selector to look for a class you can do the following which will search for a substring in the attribute value

```
li[class*="menu"]
```

However when searching classes in jQuery you are better off just using the class syntax

```
$('li.menu')
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending whether 'expanded' adds some functionality to existing 'menu', you may use the following:

```
$('li.menu').click(function(){
if ($(this).hasClass('expanded')) ...
 ...
})
```